# Android, JUnit Tests, and FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION

Tags: java, android, junit, android-testing

I have a large number of tests. When I add a few more, I get `E/JavaBinder(1705): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!`. How do I fix this? My current hack is to have multiple test `TestSuite`s that only test a select subset of my tests. There has to be a better way to do this. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this [question and response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576887/large-amount-of-unit-tests-cause-freezes-with-failed-binder-transaction), which indicates that SDK tools v8 has fixed this issue. I was running tests on an old phone with Android 2.1 (i.e., SDK v7). Newer phones should likely not encounter this issue; after using a Nexus phone running Android 4 for my tests, I no longer encountered the issue.